# What is meant by the expression: "Save the day"

Tags: meaning

What is meant by the expression "Save the day"? Does It mean to take advantage of the day? Could you provide some examples?

Comment: The usage of save in that expression means rescue.  It's used when a situation is  going bad and someone rescues it.  If the situation wasn't fixed, your day would suck.  So fixing the problem saves the day.

Comment: There's a song name "**Save the day**" played in the Ghostbusters old movie. That's when they come to rescue New York city.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Save the day" is an idiom.  It doesn't mean to take advantage of the day. If somebody saves the day, he does something to successfully prevent a likely defeat, failure, or unpleasant situation. For examples:

We are expected to lose the game, but our tailenders (lower order batsmen) played well and saved the day.

The police saved the day by coming just in the nick of time and catching the kidnappers.

We forgot to bring a knife for cutting the wedding cake, but Peter brought one and saved the day.

Comment: I like this answer; good examples. As a footnote, though, “last players” sounds a bit unidiomatic. Did you have a sport in mind when you wrote that? (In the U.S., we might say “bench players” or “reserve players” or “backup players.”)

Comment: @J.R.  I appreciate your encouraging comments. I have changed the phrase last players to tailenders.

Comment: "Tailenders" is a term used in Cricket, that British and Commonwealth people will be familiar with our American contributors may be less familiar with it.  Just as a side note "Save the Day" is sometimes used in invitations such as for weddings, meaning to make sure you leave the day free to attend the ceremony.

Comment: @Sarriesfan - In the US, those invitations usually say “Save the date”.